# How to get the direction of a marking arrow point to the tangent of decoration point on the curve

Tags: latex, tikz

I need to decorate a curve with the center of the arrow at the center of the curve. In `tikz` this can be achieved by setting the value of `pre length` equal to the length of the arrow, as in the following example

```
\draw[decoration={ pre length=8pt, markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Stealth[black,length=8pt]}}}, postaction={decorate}] (-0.5, 0.125) to [out=60, in=120] (0.5, 0.125);
```

However, now the direction of arrow is the tangent of the point where the arrow tip is, which is not symmetric and not nice at all. [image]

Is it possible to get the direction of the arrow the same as the tangent of decoration point  (`pos=0.5` here) while keeping the center of the arrow at the same position so that the picture looks symmetric ? The following picture is what I need. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [Jake's answer of getting the local coordinate system of an arbitrary point of a curve through markings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940), I tweak this out.

```
\newcommand{\appendarrow}[3]{
\tikzset{
    middlearrow/.style args={#1}{
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with
                {
                    \coordinate (exy1) at (#1/-6.0,0pt);
                    \coordinate (exy2) at (-0.5*#1,#1/3.0);  % 3.0 adjustable 
                    \coordinate (exy3) at (0.5*#1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (exy4) at (-0.5*#1,#1/-3.0); % 3.0 adjustable 
                },
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    middlearrow/.default= 3pt
}
\draw[middlearrow=#1] #3;
\fill[#2] (exy1) -- (exy2) -- (exy3) -- (exy4) -- cycle;
}
```

If we want to draw a path with a middle arrow, just use `\appendarrow{arrow size}{arrow color}{path}`. For example, `\appendarrow{6pt}{black}{(-0.5, 0.125) to [out=60, in=120] (0.5, 0.125);}` gives me the following figure
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\draw[thick, ->] (-0.5, 0.125) to [out=90, in=180] (0, 0.5);
\draw[thick] (0, 0.5) to [out=0, in=90] (0.5, 0.125);
```

To me, cutting the curve in two parts and putting a regular arrow at the end of the first curve is the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, the problem with this approach is that: first, not every path cut be easily divided into two part; second, the center of the arrow is not at the center of the path. I think I worked this out after some effort. See answer below.